# Apache working fine, except for 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache

Everything was working fine, until I detected a bug,
My server cannot access his own services on 127.0.0.1.
I'm not sure if related but when I type 127.0.0.1 in Internet Explorer, it waits, then says www.127.0.0.1 is not reachable. I did add 'www.' forced recently, but now I changed this script to 'xxx.' instead of 'www.' and it still redirects me to www.127.0.0.1, the rest of my website gets redirected to 'xxx.'

This is httpd.conf:

```
# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin admin@your-domain.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.net
ServerName 127.0.0.1

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
#DocumentRoot "c:/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "c:/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "c:/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

This is httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/htdocs
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias www.127.0.0.1 localhost www.localhost
    ErrorLog logs/example-intern-error.txt
    CustomLog logs/example-intern-access.txt common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/htdocs
    ServerName sa-arp.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net www.example.com example.com 
    ErrorLog logs/example-error.txt
    CustomLog logs/example-access.txt common

    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxx\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried all combination possible, nothing seems to work.

Please help me I am out of resources and patiente!

Thank you,

rt-2

Comment: Please post your [mcve] in the question itself instead of linking to something on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easy, the problem WAS Internet Explorer, 
I used it because I was on the server itself testing the service and didn't want to install a new program.
Well Firefox did the job and worked, problem was the testing method.
rt-2

**EDIT:** The problem was not internet explorer, the problem was that I created a 301 redirection, which means the browser remembered the first thing I told him and then all my tests were futile for every domain I already tested once.  (Yeah, that was frustrating). I updated this post just in case someone had a similar code and my issue.